# Не сходятся md5 суммы в php и c#

Tags: c#, php, md5

Есть клиентское приложение на c#, которое должно логиниться на серваке и получать некую информацию. Логин и пароль в мд5 с солью. Проблема в том, что хэши на клиенте и сервере не сходятся. 
Вот пример кода на сервере:

```
protected $login = 'admin';
protected $password = '123';
protected $salt = 'mysalt';
protected  $token;
public function __construct(){
    $this->token = md5($this->salt.md5($this->login.$this->password));
}
public function getToken()
{
    return $this->token;
}
```

А вот пример с клиента:

```
        string admin = tb1.Text;
        string password = tb2.Text;
        string token = Util.CalculateMD5Hash(Vars.salt + Util.CalculateMD5Hash(admin + password));
```

Функция расчета хэша:

```
    public static string CalculateMD5Hash(string input)
    {
        MD5 md5 = System.Security.Cryptography.MD5.Create();
        byte[] inputBytes = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(input);
        byte[] hash = md5.ComputeHash(inputBytes);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 0; i < hash.Length; i++)
        {
            sb.Append(hash[i].ToString("X2"));
        }
        return sb.ToString().ToLower();
    }
```

Проблема, похоже, со сторокой из текстбокса, потому что если в переменный admin и password занести просто строки, то хэши сходятся. Подскажите что можно сделать в этой ситуации?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Хм. А почему у вас `System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(input)`? Сомневаюсь, что ваша строка в ASCII. В .NET [строки хранятся в UTF-16](http://bytes.com/topic/c-sharp/answers/577686-encoding-textboxes), так что попробуйте [`Encoding.Unicode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.encoding.unicode.aspx).

Это на стороне .NET; правильность на стороне PHP проверьте сами :)

Comment: Поменял на Encoding.Default.GetBytes(input) и сошлись. Спасибо! :)

Comment: @DeaTh: Пожалуйста! Но вы всё же осторожнее с этой кодировкой, она машинно-зависима. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/shawnste/archive/2005/03/15/don-t-use-encoding-default.aspx

Answer (score 0):

а у вас в php кодировка случаем не UTF?